# Change Globals in TYPO3 from controller

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

In TYPO3 CMS if you want to change where the logs are being saved you need to change `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['LOG']['writerConfiguration']` and add your file location. Well, I am developing an extension that will allow the user to change this behavior but the problem is I cannot change it in run time. I mean if I write:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['LOG']['writerConfiguration'] = "some thing new'
```

And while debugging I can see it changed in $GLOBALS but it won't be changed in the Configuration afterwords.
I remember there was a function used to change/add new configurations there but I cannot find it. Can anyone help?

I am using TYPO3 CMS v9.5.5

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for 
`TYPO3\CMS\Core\Configuration\ConfigurationManager::updateLocalConfiguration()`?

```
/**
 * Override local configuration with new values.
 *
 * @param array $configurationToMerge Override configuration array
 */
```

It can be used as followed:

```
<?php
$objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
$configurationManager = $objectManager->get(ConfigurationManagerInterface::class);
$configurationManager->updateLocalConfiguration('...');
```

Comment: indeed, i did find this one. Although i didnt use read the class comment: `* IMPORTANT:
 *   This class is intended for internal core use ONLY.
 *   Extensions should usually use the resulting $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'] array,
 *   do not try to modify settings in LocalConfiguration.php with an extension.
 * @internal`

Comment: Yes, but if modifying settings is what you actually want to do...? Alternatively, you could use the localconf of your extension `ext_localconf.php`

Comment: just for the sake of knowledge i already changed the whole concept of how i want to proceed, after a lof of digging for sure

Comment: anyhow, even in ext_localconf it wont be possbile to do so because the exact value i want to change is ['LOG']['writerConfiguration'] as i mentioned and i want this to be via controller or service so the user can change it via BE extensions.

Comment: the answer it self is corrected but not encouraged by the CMS/Framework to do it which means it could be messed up with some update or has some side effects lateron (currently the answer is accepted, but its not clear for later on; thus i wont make it as an accepted one)